# scan image and convert to byte[]

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I scan a picture with wpfTwain. and display image into `System.Windows.Control.Image`.

How do I convert the image to binary?

I used the following method:

```
public byte[] getJPGFromImageControl(BitmapImage imageC)
{
       MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();              
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(imageC));//error
        encoder.Save(memStream);
        return memStream.GetBuffer();
}
```

call as :

```
getJPGFromImageControl(firmaUno.Source as BitmapImage)
```

error as :  imageC is null !!!

why?

`firmaUno.Source` is not null !! but after the use from (`firmaUno.Source as BitmapImage`) ... `BitmapImage` is null!!!!

Comment: What's the type of `firmaUno`? When you use `as`, it returns `null` if it can't be properly cast to `BitmapImage`. Seems like `firmaUno.Source` is not returning a `BitmapImage`.

Comment: firmaUno is system.windows.control.image.

Comment: To debug, try a couple of things. First, see what `firmaUno.Source.GetType().Name` returns. Also, see what happens if you use `getJPGFromImageControl((BitmapImage)firmaUno.Source)` instead.

Comment: firmaUno.Source.GetType().Name is cachedimage!!! what is cachedimage?

Comment: new error after use the getJPGFromImageControl((BitmapImage)firmaUno.Source) is cannot convert cachedimage to bitmapimage

Comment: there is just something called a BitConverter.GetBytes(object) check msdn

Comment: @keyboardP : how to use ? what is Image ?

Comment: @eranotzer - Doesn't `BitConverter` only work on base data types? Also, that would get the bytes for the actual `Image` object, not for the source.

Comment: @MMDMNC - I've posted the code, but removed the extension aspect. See if that helps.

Comment: @keyboardP maybe it works for BitmapImage as well ..

Comment: @eranotzer - There doesn't seem to be an `object` overload - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx

Comment: @MMDMNC - That method was using the `Drawing.Image` control, not `windows.control.image`. Try the `SaveImage` method here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410419/convert-system-drawing-image-to-system-windows-controls-image